ESP8266 socket server data to multiple clients
I am a bit of a newbee on this but I have managed this ESP8266 socket server used to publish AIS/GPS data on my boat-network. This cannot serve multiple clients. Clients do not send anything. Just receiving the data on port 8888. How can I sent this data to more (2) clients?
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"

int port = 8888;  //Port number
WiFiServer server(port);
String newHostname = "AISnode";

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(38400);

  GetSSID();
  delay(2000);

  WiFi.hostname("NodeMCU");

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ConSSID, PassWord); //Connect to wifi
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(1000);
  }

  server.begin();

}

void loop()

{
  WiFiClient client = server.available();

  while (client.connected())
  {
    while (client.available() > 0)
    {
      // read data from the connected client
      Serial.write(client.read());
    }
    //Send Data to connected client
    while (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
      //client.write('connected');
      client.write(Serial.read());
    }
  }
}




server.available(); will return the other clients if they try to connect

Problem solved, thanks. TCP clients stored in an array:
{
  uint8_t i;
  //check if there are any new clients
  if (server.hasClient()) {
    // new incoming connection detected

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++) {
      //find free/disconnected array place
      if (serverClients[i].connected()) {
        if (debug) {
          Serial.print(i);
          Serial.println(" is connected");
          //Serial.println(serverClients[i].status());
        }
      }
      else
      {
        // listen for incoming clients
        serverClients[i] = server.accept();
        if (serverClients[i].connected()) {
          if (debug) {
            Serial.print(i);
            Serial.println(" is NEW client");
          }
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //check clients for data
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++) {
    if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()) {
      if (serverClients[i].available()) {
        //get data from the telnet client and push it to the UART*
        while (serverClients[i].available()) Serial.write(serverClients[i].read());
      }
    }
  }
  //check SERIAL for data
  if (Serial.available()) {
    size_t len = Serial.available();
    uint8_t sbuf[len];
    Serial.readBytes(sbuf, len);

    //push Serial AIS data to all connected clients
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++) {
      //      if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()) {
      if (serverClients[i].connected()) {
        serverClients[i].write(sbuf, len);
      }
    }
  }
}


